# How delete empty values in array in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How delete empty values in array in Yii2?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'register_Time')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'Name')->textInput() ?>
```

---

```
$model['register_Time'] = ''; //NULL
$model['Name'] = 'Sveta'; // Sveta
```

---

**Model**

```
class Account extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function rules()
    {

        return [
            [['Name', 'register_Time'], 'required']
        ];
    }

}
```

How delete NULL or empty values in array?

I try -

```
$model = array_diff($model, array(''));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Grumpy Why? - Error - PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: $model is a object of class Account. It is not an array. You cannot use in in array_filter() function/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use array_filter(), which conveniently handles all this for you:

```
array_filter( $model )
```

Comment: Error -  PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Grumpy - Why? - Error - PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: just check dear. if you know PHP